# Why does the search function not work as advertised?

Tags: bug

When you click in the search bar it shows you these hints:

---

[image: search hints]

---

I take to understand the highlighted one as this: the phrase in double quotes will search for the exact quoted literal.

Not so, as the examples below show.

Am I wrong thinking that this does not work as a reasonable person would expect?

---

It ignores punctuation marks in the quoted literal:

[image]

It also ignores word case in that literal:

[image]

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267937/how-can-i-search-for-special-characters